# How do I select an element with a non-alphanumeric id using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Axl Rose's wiki page contains an element with the id:

```
1983.E2.80.931986:_Early_years
```

I'm using `$('#1983.E2.80.931986:_Early_years')` to get this element but that fails.

What's the correct selector to use if I want to select this element by id?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Straight from from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (such as
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^&a{|}~`) as a literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two backslashes: `\\.` For example, if you
>   have an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Corollary:

```
jQuery.escapeSelector = function(str) {
  return str.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\$&");
}

// ...

$('#' + $.escapeSelector('1983.E2.80.931986:_Early_years'))
```

Comment: plugin doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting : `1983\\$0E2\\$080\\$0931986\\$0_E\\$0rly_ye\\$0rs` from the plugin

Comment: You could manually escape the characters, of course. `#1983\\.E2\\.80\\.931986\\:_Early_years` is the end result you want.

Comment: are you sure your escapeSelector can work? I try it on AXL ROSE' wiki page but it still return empty set.

Comment: @Dorsey Try again, I've fixed the regex a minute ago.

Comment: it still can't work. you can try it on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axl_Rose by yourself.

Comment: @Dorsey Ah, my mistake. In fact you have to escape the character with one backslash (not two). The docs speak of two because you have to type `"\\."` to get `"\."`. I took it too literally. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

Since there are those types of characters, I personally find that the easiest and most readable way is to search by ID itself such as:

`$('[id*="1983.E2.80.931986:_Early_years"]')​​​​​​​ // will search for the ID anywhere`

Much easier and less confusing way than having to escape characters, etc. *Especially* since if you ever change the ID name somehow, you won't have to worry about it's naming.

This makes the most sense if you build this ID *dynamically* from back-end code, it'll always prepulate correctly and work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yt8D9/

Comment: the starts-with selector is slower than the class selector (per jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) which is slower than the id selector. If performance is an issue this could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, good to know! I suppose using `*` would be better then! Doesn't look like a performance issue there. http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: possibly true.  also probably premature optimization on my part.

Answer (score 3):

you can use javascript for that

document.getElementById('1983.E2.80.931986:_Early_years')

Answer (score 1):

escape the `:` and `.`

```
$('#1983\\.E2\\.80.931986\\:_Early_years')
```

Answer (score 1):

The **:** disrupt the selection because it's reserved by css pseudoclasses (e.g. :hover). Try backslashing the **:**

Answer (score 1):

[Escape it](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) using '\\' :

```
$('#1983\\.E2\\.80\\.931986\\:_Early_years')
```