# is there any function which can help escape all meta-characters contained in jquery‘s selector？

Tags: javascript, jquery

Straight from jquery docs：

If you wish to use any of the meta-characters (such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^&a{|}~)` as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you have an element with `id="foo.bar"`, you can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

I want to know is there any function can help me to escape those meta-charcters？

Comment: You can start by solving this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846311/how-to-select-an-element-with-a-non-alphanumeric-id-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/aspConf/aspConf/Exterminating-Common-jQuery-Bugs?format=html5) about jQuery bugs, the author has a function he wrote that uses regexs to properly escape all jQuery selectors @52:18. Side note: the video is great, every developer using jQuery should watch it.

Transcribed for posterity:

```
String.prototype.escapeSelector = function () {
    return this.replace(
        /([$%&()*+,./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^\{|}~])/g,
        '\\$1'
    );
};
```

You would use this like so:

```
$('#' + 'foo.bar'.escapeSelector());
```

Comment: Not "convenience" but posterity

Comment: Hash is missing here, there is a more accurate answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11846367/1780648