# query selector in jquery causing unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I plug in the following into my console (Chrome):

```
$('input[name=shopping-cart.merchant-private-data]');
```

it results in:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=shopping-cart.merchant-private-data]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846661/is-there-any-function-which-can-help-escape-all-meta-characters-contained-in-jqu/11846715#11846715

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real problem (and solution) actually dawned on me while posting.

The issue is the decimal place in the selector. You need to escape it with two backslashes like so:

```
$('input[name=shopping-cart\\.merchant-private-data]');
```

Comment: Alternatively you can place quotes around the attribute value.

Comment: @Cek: You have to wait a certain period (I think it's a day) to accept your own answer.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to accept my question and SOF said I have to wait two days :( In fact I used the SOF option where you can answer the question on submit. I'm surprised it doesn't put the check there by default..

Answer (score 0):

when creating selectors based on the value of an attribute, you should always surround the value in quotes:

```
$('input[name="shopping-cart.merchant-private-data"]');
```